# How to use Stingtokenizer for find max score?

Tags: java

I am working on the following form:

[image: my Form]

I need to be able to click the max button to read the text file. Then, use Stringtokenizer and find max score. As a result, I should output student_ID name and max score.

```
JButton Button_MAX = new JButton();
        Button_MAX.setBounds(260, 170, 140, 30);
        Button_MAX.setFont(font);
        Button_MAX.setText("MAX");
        getContentPane().add(Button_MAX);
        Button_MAX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            }   
        });
```

**example.**

Expected result:

[image: desired result]

Comment: Having bad English is not an excuse for a complete misuse of punctuation, formatting and extremely poor question content. Please read this before you post anything more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i ve correctly understood your request :

1) To read a text file, in Java 8+ you can use :

```
Stream<String> lines=Files.lines(Paths.get("myFile.txt"))
```

(see https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/)

2) I assume that you text file contains numbers, so you can do : (Java 8+)

```
    int max=0;
    lines.forEach(

        (line) -> {
          StringTokenizer stk=new StringTokenizer(line);
          while(stk.hasMoreTokens())
          {
               int val=Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
               if (val>max)
               {
                   max=val;
               }
          }
        }
      );
```